# How to delete history of a reverted file? (p4v)

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

First of all, I apologize if the terminology is not correct. I have only recently started using P4 and am having some trouble with it.

Let's say I have a file called Program.cs. There are two versions of this file: Version #1 and #2. I realized that I have accidentally committed the changes to the server, so I want to go back to Version #1 without leaving any trace of Version #2.

What I have done so far:

```
-Go to P4V GUI 
-Right click on the file I want to revert
-Select "Get revision..."
-Under "Specify revision using:" -> Revision -> 1 (in the "Enter revision number" box)
-Check "Force Operation" box
```

This seems to revert the file, but the GUI then displays a little yellow triangle next to the file. When I hover above it, it says "not latest revision of file (#1 of 2)"

What I want to do, is completely erase any record that there has indeed been a Revision #2, since #2 is the product of my acute n00bish-ness and should never have been submitted at all.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: The first step toward really enjoying and getting value out of your SCM system is to realize that you never need to erase that unwanted revision. It's doing no harm; in fact, it is actually helpful, in the long run, to record all these false steps and mis-starts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to ever delete a file permanently is to obliterate. You'll probably need admin privileges (I very rarely ever obliterate anything), you can either use the Admin console, or the command line http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/obliterate.html

Or, since you already have revision 1, check it out, resolve, taking your changes, then submit. There will be 3 revisions, but 1 and 3 will be exactly alike.

Even easier, revert the file, and then just right click on version 1 in the history and select "Rollback to Revision"